# How to calculate cyclomatic complexity?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

There is a React Native application, I want to make a cyclomatic complexity analysis.

Please, tell me what are the ready tools for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ESLint for this](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/complexity#rule-details). Be aware that "[if you can’t determine an appropriate complexity limit for your code, then it’s best to disable this rule.](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/complexity#when-not-to-use-it)"

Comment: This rule seems to be specific to the JS language syntax itself, and doesn't do any cyclomatic complexity analysis for react code?

Answer (score -1):

You can use eslint and enable (cyclometric) complexity tests:

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/complexity